# android get user input from activity to another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, input

I want to wirte an android app that will read input from user each time i press abutton and will handle it in different thread(not activity) also i dont want to open new thread each time i need an example for that.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please specify some code, what have you tried so far. Or do you want people to write an app for you?

Comment: If you need to communicate between activities, you can use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the text from user input field:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);
final String text = editText.getText().toString;
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do something with String text
    }
};

handler.post(r);
```

Or this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // do something with String text
    }
}).start();
```

You can find info about threads in Android here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: if i want that each time i press a button it will do the activity? ineed to open new thread each time?

Comment: Look into the documentation on [Worker threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) or maybe you could use AsyncTask that are mentioned in the same section.

Answer (score 0):

you could use this link [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers)

```
`Thread thread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // do something here
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
thread.start();`
```